# OpenGTS gps tracking system

Tags: c#, gps, opengts

i have a windows server and need to publish the OpenGts system to my server, is it possible?

I already launch it, but i am not able to publish it.

Regards

Comment: What have you tried already, what didn't work, how will you proceed, how does the infrastructure look like, etc.? Some more details would be nice.

Comment: Thank you Jan_V , actually i didnt try any thing yet, i just want to begin and know the first step to begin trying. Thanks